# Find dates when exactly records changed for user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to find the dates when exactly the status really changed.

Order should be analysed from Start to end period:

```
Start Period : 11-10-2014
End Period : 21-10-2014
```

Data:

```
ID, Name, Effective_date, Status
1   A       21-10-2014      OFF
2   A       20-10-2014      OFF
3   A       19-10-2014      On
4   A       18-10-2014      On
5   A       17-10-2014      On
6   A       16-10-2014      OFF
7   A       15-10-2014      On
8   A       14-10-2014      On
9   A       13-10-2014      OFF
10  A       12-10-2014      OFF
11  A       11-10-2014      OFF
```

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Expected output:

```
ID, Name, Effective_date, Status

2   A       20-10-2014      OFF
5   A       17-10-2014      On
6   A       16-10-2014      OFF
8   A       14-10-2014      On
11  A       11-10-2014      OFF
```

Comment: ...checking calendar... solutions for this type of problem are much easier to write, and perform much better, on SQL Server 2005 and above. Is there a reason you're clinging to this 15-year old version that has been out of any type of support for years?

Comment: There is a reason and thats why I mentioned the version. I can easily resolve it on version above than 2005 using pivot.

Comment: Can there be gaps in the dates? Or it is guaranteed that there is one row for every consecutive date?

Answer (score 3):

```
-- Guessed table definition
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example
(
    [ID]            integer NOT NULL,
    [Name]          char(1) NOT NULL,
    EffectiveDate   datetime NOT NULL,
    [Status]        varchar(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT CUQ_dbo_Example_Name_EffectiveDate
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([Name], EffectiveDate DESC),

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Example_ID
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID])
);


-- Sample data from the question
INSERT dbo.Example (ID, Name, EffectiveDate, [Status])
SELECT 1, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '21-10-2014', 105), 'OFF' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '20-10-2014', 105), 'OFF' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '19-10-2014', 105), 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '18-10-2014', 105), 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '17-10-2014', 105), 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '16-10-2014', 105), 'OFF' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '15-10-2014', 105), 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '14-10-2014', 105), 'On' UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '13-10-2014', 105), 'OFF' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '12-10-2014', 105), 'OFF' UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'A', CONVERT(datetime, '11-10-2014', 105), 'OFF';
```

Solution:

```
-- Query
SELECT
    E.[ID],
    E.[Name],
    E.EffectiveDate,
    E.[Status]
FROM dbo.Example AS E
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM dbo.Example AS E2
        WHERE E2.[Name] = E.[Name]
        AND E2.[Status] = E.[Status]
        AND E2.EffectiveDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, E.EffectiveDate)
    )
ORDER BY
    E.Name,
    E.EffectiveDate DESC;
```

Execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*
from tableName t 
join tableName tt
    on (tt.ID = t.ID+1 and tt.[Status] <> t.[Status]) 
union
select * from (select top 1 * from tableName order by Effective_date)T
```

it's not pretty, but works

Comment: You should add that it works only if `ID` values have no gaps.